# DataLossError when running pretrained model inception_v4

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am trying to run `vectorize_pretrained.py` using `InceptionV4` model type from **Oliver Edholm** model, see https://github.com/OliverEdholm/Image-Retrieval

I got the following error:

> DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file ./embedding/extraction/inception_v4.py: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
>        [[Node: save/RestoreV2_475 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_475/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_475/shape_and_slices)]]

When I run the same file using `VGG16` model type I got the same error.

Does anyone have a suggestion?